# getting info about primary and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I want to get information about primary keys and foreign keys of a table.can this be done? and how?
i have tried getExportedKeys , getImportedKeys , getCrossReference methods in DatabaseMetaData class. but it is returning an empty resultset. this is the code -

```
import java.sql.*;


    DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();

    ResultSet rs = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "employee");
    System.out.println("dfds");

    while (rs.next()) {

      String columnName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
      System.out.println("getPrimaryKeys(): columnName=" + columnName);
      System.err.println ("PK_NAME:" + rs.getObject (6)); 

    }


    st.close();
    conn.close();


}

public static Connection getMySqlConnection() throws Exception {
     Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();  
     String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/foodmart";
        String user = "root";
        String passwd = "root";


    Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
    return conn;
  }
```

Comment: Those methods should work, but I believe that with MySQL you need to enable some connection property to get full metadata support (although I thought that foreign key and primary key info should be available without this property set). Also make sure your database actually has foreign keys. Also consider case sensitivity (eg `EMPLOYEE` vs `employee`)

Answer (score 0):

Query information_schema for primary and foreign keys:

```
select *
from information_schema.key_column_usage 
where table_name = 'employee';
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html

Comment: My guess is that the TS wants to have the JDBC way of retrieving this information.

Comment: I give to the data base all the grant but i still not get the reseult of metadata aboyt the pk and the fk ??

Answer (score 0):

You already have your primary keys. I do not bother you in repeat your code.

Foreign keys are reported by:

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = meta.getCrossReference(...);
```

Warning: Foreign-keys might have comments. The jdbc standard api do not report remarks / comments the fks might have.